# Вычисление корня в Windows Form в Visual C++

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli

Создавая приложение Windows Form и добавления вычисления корня возникает ошибка.

> System::Math: класс, объявленный как "abstract", не предусматривает создание экземпляров.

Для вычисления использую функцию `Math.Sqrt`

Форма записи такова: `b = Math.Sqrt(a);`

Comment: Кто там за опечатку голосует? Ну не опечатка же. Нормальный вопрос.

Comment: @Qwertiy,  а мне кажется, что вопрос не нормальный. ТС привел только вменяемо написанный текст ошибки. Но вопрос звучит не "что такое абстрактный класс", и не "как вызвать метод абстрактного класса", и не "почему такой класс не предусматривает создание экземпляра". В текущей постановке это "код не компилируется, помогите исправить" безо всякой попытки самостоятельного решения.

Comment: @GreenDragon, и какую попытку решения ты бы хотел увидеть?

Comment: @Qwertiy, я бы хотел вообще не видеть такие вопросы. А попытка решения в данном случае - осмысление текста выданного компилятором.

Comment: @GreenDragon, он вызывает статическую функцию, но вместо вызова получает ошибку пр создание инстанса абстрактного класса. Я сам подобную ошибку когда-то гуглил. Потому что было неожиданно, что надо через другой знак писать.

Comment: @Qwertiy, я тоже когда-то получил эту ошибку и с легкостью нашел ответ. Подозреваю, что вы тоже не стали бы постить такой вопрос, особенно составленный так, как это было сделано в оригинальной формулировке.

Comment: Я не против таких вопросов, но против одобрения вопросов, составленных без малейшей предварительной подготовки. Особенно если он небрежно сформулирован и видно только типичное желание "студента" решить следствие, а не понять причину.

Comment: @GreenDragon поясните пожалуйста, почему по вашему мнению вопрос не относится к С++, а относится именно к С++CLI ?

Comment: @Kromster, C++/CLI это не C++. В текущей формулировке вопрос про конкретную ошибку, связанную с конкретной попыткой использования класса из фреймворка .Net.  Тут даже и метка WinForms лишняя, т.к. вопрос не содержит ничего, относящегося к данной технологии.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> b = Math.Sqrt(a);
> ```

```
b = Math::Sqrt(a);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Всё заработало.

Comment: @КириллКузнецов, ответ прими нажатием на галочку слева от него.

Comment: Поясните что означают фрагменты кода в вашем ответе?

Comment: @Kromster, в цитате код из вопроса, а потом код, как это надо было записать правильно. Вроде очевидно, не?

Comment: @Qwertiy кажется неправильным, давать ответ без пояснений.

Comment: @Kromster, хоть вы и правы, но какой вопрос, таков и ответ.